# Accessing name of randomly chosen list

Tags: python

I have this list :

```
availableMaterials = [Si3N4_nk, Y2O3_nk, Al2O3_nk, TiO2_nk, SiO2_nk]
```

where each element is itself a list. In a function, I randomly choose an element and return it :

```
material1_nk = random.choice(availableMaterials)
return material1_nk
```

material1_nk will then be a list. Where I call this function, I would like to know which element was chosen by accessing the name (Si3N4, Y2O3, etc.).
What is an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Once you put those lists in the list of lists, their original variable name can no longer be associated to them. Maybe you should use a dictionary instead.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. Are you sure you're not confusing lists and dictionaries?

Comment: Do you want a function that get `Si3N4` and return `Si3N4_nk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you put those lists into the list of lists, their original variable name can no longer be associated to them. Maybe you should use a dictionary instead.

```
availableMaterials = {"Si3N4": Si3N4_nk, "Y2O3": Y2O3_nk, "Al2O3": Al2O3_nk, 
                      "TiO2": TiO2_nk, "SiO2": SiO2_nk]
material = random.choice(availableMaterials.keys())
print "Selected Material:", material
print "List Contents:", availableMaterials[material]
```